# How to use options in js-beautify plugin

Tags: javascript, plugins, js-beautify

JS noob here. I'm currently using js-beautify(https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify) plugin to properly indent/format a long string of HTML code. This is how I'm using it

```
html_beautify(HTML);
```

HTML is a variable containing regular HTML code.
How can I pass options like disabling word-wrap or removing empty lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can add an object as the second parameter to handle your options:

```
html_beautify(elHTML, { preserve_newlines: false, wrap_line_length: 0 });
```